# Property value in this.props.params turn into 'a' for some reason. I am console.logging in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am logging the the params value in the componentDidMount at this component  :

```
import React from 'react';
import VideoSingle from './VideoSingle';

class Single extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.params,'params value')

  }

  render(){

    return (

      <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center ">
        <VideoSingle {...this.props}  /> 
      </div>

    );
  }
};

export default Single;
```

Picture showing the results of my console.log, I am entering  'http://localhost:3001/course/20/video/3' directly in the URL

[image]

The problematic route looks like is this one : '/course/:courseId/video/:videoId'. These are the routes that I am using (react-router) :

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

// Import Components
import App from './components/App';
import Single from './components/Single';
import VideoGrid from './components/VideoGrid';
import CourseGrid from './components/CourseGrid';

// Import react router deps
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store, { history } from './store';

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={CourseGrid} />
        <Route path="/course/:courseId" component={VideoGrid}></Route>
        <Route path='/course/:courseId/video/:videoId' component={Single}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

I can't figure it out why the property value in the 'this.props.params' turns into 'a'. I want to know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Repo : https://github.com/phelpa/YouList

Comment: why is `componentDidMount` running 3 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out why , the `<VideoSingle>` component that was being rendered had :

```
<iframe title = 'iframeYoutube' className="h-100 w-100 db  br2 br--top"
      src={'a'} frameBorder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
      allowFullScreen="allowFullScreen"></iframe>
```

For some reason the `src={'a'}` was 'leaking' into this.props.params.videoId and for some reason it was being rendered 3 times

I changed the src={'a'} to a actual source like `src={'https://www.youtube.com/embed/fB0IHPGuTFo'}`

and the problem stopped.